# how to delete files have specific pattern in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a set of images like these

```
12345-image-1-medium.jpg 12345-image-2-medium.png 12345-image-3-large.jpg
```

what pattern should I write to select these images and delete them

I also have these images that don't want to select

```
12345-image-profile-small.jpg 12345-image-profile-medium.jpg 12345-image-profile-large.png
```

I have tried this regex but not worked

```
1234-image-[0-9]+-small.*
```

I think bash not support regex as in Javascript, Go, Python or Java

Comment: Are there any other images in this directory that should not be deleted and if so what are their names?

Comment: yeah there are other images
eg: 12345-image-profile-small.jpg
that I don't want to delete

Comment: Did you try a pattern that didn't work? What was it?

Comment: yeah but the tricky part is selecting the number part.

Comment: Test with `ls -al [[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]-image-[[:digit:]]*` if that matches what you want to delete, then `rm [[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]-image-[[:digit:]]*`

Comment: I have just tested this regex
1234-image-[0-9]+-.*
but not worked.
it worked in online regex tester https://regex101.com/ but when I use it with ls it not work
ls 1234-image-[0-9]+-.*

Comment: What I posted in the comment requires 5 digits then `"-image-"` and another digit. If you have varying number of digits, you will need to take another path. Basic regex is another option.

Comment: ok tnx.
do bash not support regex ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, bash does not use regular expressions.  Its syntax is called "globbing". https://linuxhint.com/bash_globbing_tutorial/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I solve it with this pattern

```
12345-image-*[0-9]-*
```

eg:

```
rm -rf 12345-image-*[0-9]-*
```

it matches all the file names start with `12345-image-` then a `number` then `-` symbol and any thing after that

as I found it's `globbing` in bash not `regex`
and I found this [app](https://codepen.io/mrmlnc/full/OXQjrZ) really use full

Comment: That will match a whole lot more than you think, but only if the filenames start with `12345`. From your comment of `"I have just tested this regex 1234-image-..."` you indicated that the number of digits was not fixed at five -- it this a requirement?.

Comment: as I tested it worked. I just want to select files start with specific id then have -image- then a number and an extension at the end

Answer (score 1):

```
for pic in 12345*.{jpg,png};do rm $pic;done
```

for more information on wildcards take a look [here](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm)

Comment: I have just edited the question plz have a check on update

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029287/how-to-write-a-pattern-to-delete-images-start-with-specific-text-in-linux#comment109708718_62029287

Answer (score 1):

So long as you do NOT have filenames with embedded `'\n'` character, then the following `find` and `grep` will do:

```
find . -type f | grep '^.*/[[:digit:]]\{1,5\}-image-[[:digit:]]\{1,5\}'
```

It will find all files below the current directory and match (1 to 5 digits) followed by `"-image-"` followed by another (1 to 5 digits). In your case with the following files:

```
$ ls -1
123-image-99999-small.jpg
12345-image-1-medium.jpg
12345-image-2-medium.png
12345-image-3-large.jpg
12345-image-profile-large.png
12345-image-profile-medium.jpg
12345-image-profile-small.jpg
```

The files you request are matched in addition to `123-image-99999-small.jpg`, e.g.

```
$ find . -type f | grep '^.*/[[:digit:]]\{1,5\}-image-[[:digit:]]\{1,5\}'
./123-image-99999-small.jpg
./12345-image-3-large.jpg
./12345-image-2-medium.png
./12345-image-1-medium.jpg
```

You can use the above in a command substitution to remove the files, e.g.

```
$ rm $(find . -type f | grep '^.*/[[:digit:]]\{1,5\}-image-[[:digit:]]\{1,5\}')
```

The remaining files are:

```
$ l1
12345-image-profile-large.png
12345-image-profile-medium.jpg
12345-image-profile-small.jpg
```

---

**If Your `find` Supports `-regextype`**

If your `find` supports the `regextype` allowing you to specify which set of regular expression syntax to use, you can use `-regextype grep` for `grep` syntax and use something similar to the above to remove the files with the `-execdir` option, e.g.

```
$ find . -type f -regextype grep -regex '^.*/[[:digit:]]\+-image-[[:digit:]]\+.*$' -execdir rm '{}' +
```

I do not know whether this is supported by BSD or Solaris, etc.., so check before turning it loose in a script. Also note, `[[:digit:]]\+` tests for (1 or more) digits and is not limited to 5-digits as shown in your question.